# How to update Data by using Hibernate in createSQLQuery

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a "table" with column id(int)name(string),size(string),quantity(int)

And I want to update quantity for minus one with every time I call it. here is my code it is working fine (no error or exception) but not updating quantity.

I have search in internet and someone say that it can be resolve in update the hibernate version from 3.0 to 3.2. But I have a question is that how can I check my hibernate version and how do i update it.

I am new to Hibernate and do not know much of its syntax. please help me. Thanks a lot.

```
    public Object upItem(Class<?> objclass,Integer id){
    String up="update dbo.TB_ITEM set quantity=quantity-1 where id="; 
    String minus=String.valueOf(id);
    String both=up+minus;

    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(both).executeUpdate();}
```

Comment: p.s.  After I using System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString()); to check my version . It says my version is in 4.2.21.Final . So I think it not the version problem cause me can't updating quantity

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a transaction. Try the following code

```
    public Object upItem(Class<?> objclass, Integer id) {
        String up = "update dbo.TB_ITEM set quantity=quantity-1 where id=";
        String minus = String.valueOf(id);
        String both = up + minus;

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // Start the transaction
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        int result = session.createSQLQuery(both).executeUpdate();
        // commit your changes
        tx.commit();
        return result;
    }
```